# Implementing virtual concepts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

my question is more of a general nature.

I know about scopes in rails but i am running into a concept that i am not able to wrap my my head around

I have a few tables in the db - like customers, products, sales etc. And i have various sales persons who are logging in to view their sales, etc. I want to implement a concept of "My" so when a sales person comes in they are only able to see their sales, their customers, the products they sold etc. So something like my.customers or my.sales or my.territories etc.

How can i implement this? how can i prefix "my" onto customers, sales etc to achieve this elegantly ?

Guidance is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: you should take a look at activerecord models. Basic table association should be able to do this with ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

This is what you use to associate and manage what the user sees, and how you access it in your controllers/views. For example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

This would make it so that a client has many sales, and you can access it using `Client.first.sales...` for example.

To make it `my` instead of `User.first`, you can use:

```
private

def my
  User.first
end
```

Comment: hi IT Ninja - thanks. When i log in I have my user id in the session, and I understand that User.first.sales could fetch all the sales by this user - but the question was how to use "my" instead of user.first - that just makes it so much more elegant and concise. I figured out the answer though - I created a class called "My" and have it a my_id_is attr_accessor - this way i can set my user id in it - then i wrote a method called customers in it - which fetches customers based off of my_id_is. So now when i call my.customers - the magic works. Thanks for your interest though.

Comment: If you're not using associations, it's definitely something you should look at, as they can give you a lot of additional flexibility further down the track, instead of you having to reinvent the wheel each time. Also, it's very common to implement a `current_user` method that returns the current user (even if it's a simple as returning `User.find(session[:user_id]`), and that method would generally be used where you're using your `My` model (which seems like a fairly redundant model that would just duplicate a subset of the behaviour of `User`).